# Gradle Distribution URL issue in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Facing error -"The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip' does not exist." when I'm running android studio normally.

But if I start the android studio as administrator above error is not coming.
I tried deleting the .gradle and .idea file and restarting the android studio, but same error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

So, after trying out lot of solutions on stack nth helped and sort out this problem. Eventually, I had to restore my android studio to default settings. So, that how my problem was resolved.